# Writing neat branching conditions

Tags: python

### Problem

I have 5 boolean variables `is_A` through `is_E` and their combinations correspond to different downstream operations. However, currently I need to write a 32 conditionals that look like

```py
if xxx:
# do something
elif is_A == True & is_B == False & ... & is_E == True:
# do something
...
elif xxx:
# do something
else xxx:
# do something
```

However, those conditionals look ugly to me and it is quite boring to write those boilerplate.

I am wondering if there is more elegant way to write them?

Comment: If you use nested if statements, it will bring down the comparisons to 20 since you will have to write 4 `if`s per variable. I am thinking if we can do better.

Comment: I mean, there could be. Are there any patterns? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Depending on why you're in this situation, you might want to use a dispatch table, or you might want to refactor your code so you don't have this giant 32-way branch based on 5 booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative syntax would be to use the `any` and `all` functions. Both of them take an iterable like a list as an argument.
`any` returns `True` if any of the conditions is `True` like logical `or` and `all` returns `True` only if all of its values evaluate to `True` like logical `and`.
Secondly, do not use `==True` and `==False`

```
elif all([ is_A, not is_B,..., is_E]):
```

And in Python, the logical AND operator is `and`, `&` is Bitwise AND.